# On the first recruiter call, is it appropriate to ask about roles that may open in the near future?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, job-search, recruitment

I have a call with an internal recruiter tomorrow and we're going to discuss a role that I think is a strong fit for my background, and that is somewhat interesting to me.

However, there's another role that I might be a better fit for, but that isn't available on the job site right now. I was made aware of the role 4 months ago (when it was just filled), and was told by someone who works at the company that new ones may open in January.

That hasn't happened yet.

When on the call tomorrow, how do I ask about whether that role will be opening soon? I'm concerned it would be seen as a bait-and-switch since the call is to discuss the already-open role, but my main message is "I like this role and would be happy to interview, but think I might be a better fit (and more interested) for this role and wonder if a) you feel the same based on my background and b) foresee that role opening up soon."

I'm wondering if it's a common thing to ask and the best way to ask.

Comment: Can you clarify - when you say "recruiter" do you mean an independent third party recruiter, who is trying to get you connected with a specific employer? Or do you mean an internal recruiter working for a specific employer? Answers may be slightly different.

Comment: @dwizum thanks for clarifying. I mean internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that this is a recruiter call, and not a direct interview for the company, I'd say, go ahead and ask about the other role you're more interested in. However, don't start with that discussion, have the scheduled discussion first, and then, additionally ask for more information on the other open positions for that organization.

For the recruiter, what matters is to fill the already open positions - so if an opening is there, they should be happy to inform you about that.

However, if the recruiter says that the position is not available, or they don't have any info on that regard, you can try to reach out to the organization (via the job portal / email) to check whether there's an opening for the role already, or it's coming up shortly.

Comment: _Dear Downvoter, along with the downvote, if you can leave a comment mentioning what is not useful about the answer, and how it can possibly be improved, it'll be helpful. Thanks._

Comment: Aaaah, I have lost my faith on that quite some time ago... Don't know mine but your answer seems ok... +1 to compensate

Comment: @DarkCygnus I guess someone lost their key, the Q and all the A are DV'd.

Comment: Not the first time I see this sort of thing ..

Comment: @DarkCygnus Can't say my first either, though in TWP it's rare, a regular thing in SO (at times, I got really frustrated with this, TBH).

Answer (score 2):

> When on the call tomorrow, how do I ask about whether that role will be opening soon?

If this is something you want to find out, I would try not to mention it during your call tomorrow (which is for a different position). The interviewer may not know the answer to that.

The exception would be if you see a proper moment or opening during the interview where you can ask that, like being prompted if you have considered other positions with them besides the one you are interviewing, or similar.

Worst case, asking about that is unlikely to harm you. If any, it shows that you are interested and enthusiastic about the company and what they do.

In any case, I would instead call the company on a separate instance, and inquiry if the position is available or if they have any information regarding its status.

Comment: I can imagine it being harmfull. It suggests OP is more interested in another type of role than the one that OP is currently being considered for.

Comment: @user180146 I think it really depends on the context of the specific employer. My current employer actually asks applicants if they would be interested in other positions as a standard screening question. It's not always considered negative.

Comment: @dwizum context is ofcourse everything and I did not want to suggest that it is always harmfull I did just not fully agree with the statement "asking about that is unlikely to harm you"